# How to see all URLs retrieved in a tab (Google Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, url

Is there a way to see all the URLs which are called when I access a website in Chrome?

Comment: I use Ublock Origin for that.  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en

Comment: Once installed use the icon at the top right to show urls that are loaded and ones that it has blocked.

Comment: One option would be NoScript, but that's Firefox-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Hit <kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome to open the developer tools.
- Choose "Sources".

[image]

Comment: While the sources tab is useful, if you want to really see ALL of the requests that are made by the browser, including ajax requests, etc the "Network" tab is where you should be looking.